# Preposition at the end of sentence

Tags: cover-letter

Is it wrong to have a preposition at the end of sentence?

In the context of writing a statement of purpose, I cannot of any substitute for the following sentence:

> I have made many small and big improvements in my life that as a
>   Middle Eastern female, I’m very proud of.

I know I can say:

> I'm proud of many small and big changes that I made in my life.

But it doesn't have the feeling that I like. Is there any other way to say it correctly with the same strong feeling?

Comment: Put a comma after "that"  for grammar and I think your sentence is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not wrong. However, in a cover letter, you should strive for clarity and maybe objectivity.

You need to put yourself in the shoes of the person that is going to read that. What information do you want to convey? Your achievements? Your feelings about your achievements?

I think that just by putting your achievement in the cover letter already implies you are proud of them. We don't want to embarrass ourselves for free, after all.

Therefore, you are not wrong, but you are not also getting the maximum out of your words. I think you could improve in some ways (this list is not exhaustive).

1. Language barrier. A middle-eastern female probably don't have English as a mother language. You could've grown up in an English home but the community you're inserted in probably isn't made of only English speakers. On low to average proficiency levels, it might cause your phrase structure to sound odd to natives.
2. Is your ethnical background relevant to the cover letter? Think about it.
3. What are your achievements? Should you describe them objectively? Show what improvements you made and why each of them is relevant.
4. Let your words convey your feelings and opinions indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

The following two forms are both grammatical:

> [Noun] that I am [abstract noun] of.
>   [Noun], of which I am [abstract noun].

Thus, if you feel the need not to end with a proposition (and there are many cases in the English language where it *cannot* be avoided; there is no genuine rule against doing so), then you could rephrase your sentence as follows:

> I have made many small and big improvements in my life, of which — as a Middle Eastern female — I am very proud.

(Note that I have also contained the subordinate clause — *"as a Middle Eastern female"* — between em dashes, to prevent excessive commas!)